# Skiasharp DrawBitmap only White

Tags: maui, skiasharp

I want to cut a part out of a SkBitmap and paint it to a new Bitmap. Therefore i tried to adopt the tutorial stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing with the difference that i do not want to display the Canvas but just get the new bitmap and transform it into a byte[] so that i can send it to the backend to. When i ignore the painting part and just convert the sourceMap back to a byte[] i get the image i uploaded as expected, however when i use the canvas and draw on the new BHitmap i just get white space and thats it. Nothing on there and i do not understand why. I also tried copying the Bitmap of the uploaded Image to check if at least then any Image would appear but still i get only blank white space.

```
public async void UploadImage()
    {
        FileResult im = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions()
        {
            FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images,
        });
        byte[] bytes = null;
        using (Stream ms = await im.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        SKBitmap sourceMap = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            sourceMap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
        }
        //SKBitmap destination = new SKBitmap(sourceMap.Width,sourceMap.Height);
        SKBitmap destination = sourceMap.Copy();
        SKRect dest = new SKRect(sourceMap.Height / 4, sourceMap.Height / 4, sourceMap.Width / 4, -sourceMap.Height / 4);
        SKRect source = new SKRect(sourceMap.Height/4,sourceMap.Height/4,sourceMap.Width/4,-sourceMap.Height/4);
        
        using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(destination))
        {
            canvas.Clear();
            canvas.DrawBitmap(sourceMap, source, dest);
        }
        SKImage skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(destination);
        SKData encoded = skImage.Encode();
        using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoded.AsStream().CopyTo(memory);
            Image = memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The View:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         xmlns:ImageCroppingTry2="clr-namespace:ImageCroppingTry2"
         x:DataType="ImageCroppingTry2:MainPageViewModel"
         x:Class="ImageCroppingTry2.MainPage">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Image x:Name="displayImage" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding UploadImageCommand}"></Button>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: First, `canvas.Clear();` can take an skcolor as an optional parameter. If you supply some color, does that color show up? If you comment out `canvas.DrawBitmap...`, does that color show up?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I tried

`using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(destination))
            {
                canvas.Clear(new SKColor().Red);
                //canvas.DrawBitmap(sourceMap, source, dest);
            }
`
but the result is still a blank white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a HeightRequest property for Image to see if it works.

I also made a small demo based on my picture which works well. You could have a try:

```
    private byte[] image;
    public byte[] Image
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image)));
        }
    }


[RelayCommand]
public async void UploadImage()
{
    //Well i pick a photo for convenience 
    FileResult im = await MediaPicker.Default.PickPhotoAsync();

    // here I think what you do is a little bit complicated, you don't have to convert stream => byte => stream => skbitmap
    SKBitmap sourceMap;
    using (Stream s = await im.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await s.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            sourceMap = SKBitmap.Decode(ms);
        }
    }

    // i don't know the image you use, please make sure the pixel you get is valid
    SKBitmap destination = new SKBitmap(100, 100);
    SKRect dest = new SKRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    SKRect source = new SKRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(destination))
    {
        canvas.Clear();
        canvas.DrawBitmap(sourceMap, source, dest);
    }

    SKImage skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(destination);
    SKData encoded = skImage.Encode();
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoded.AsStream().CopyTo(memory);
        Image = memory.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I think your project have more details and need more debug. Just make sure each output is valid.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly fine. I am wondering what was wrong with my try since from my understanding, apart fro mthe overcomplicated transformation to the SKBitmap i did exactly the same. Thank you very much. 

Second question: Do you know where the origin in the coordinates of the SKRect is? We give only the coordinates of two points but where lies the reference point?

Comment: Ok i encountered a strange behaviour i do not understand. When i use your Height and Width it works, but when i change the SKREcts to this:

`SKRect dest = new SKRect(-sourceMap.Width/4, sourceMap.Height/4, sourceMap.Width/4, -sourceMap.Height/4);
            SKRect source = new SKRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
`
i get blank white space again. I do not understand this since all coordinates are smaller than the sourceMap it must show up and because of the - signs the rectangle cannot be 0 as well.

Comment: The origin is the upper left corner of image. You could see this demo [Copying and modifying bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing#copying-and-modifying-bitmaps)

Comment: you use -sourceMap.Width/4 that may go out the Image control x-axis left boundary

Comment: Maybe set a backgrondcolor for Image could help you debug

Comment: The Image control determines the position on the page as the skrect coordinate is based on the image control. You could set the Image verticaloption or horizontaloption property to set bitmap display at the center of the page.

Comment: To keep it simpelr i have made a new question regardign my problems understandign the coordinates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75625039/understanding-skiasharp-and-maui-coordinates I would be glad if you could help me there.

Comment: I saw this thread. Just a suggestion: you may put the xaml in your question that would help people better understand your question.